# Python. I'm curious if my solution to solve this programming issue is odd? Also, what might be a proper solution from someone who has more experience

Tags: python

I was doing a google python exercise and I came up with a solution that worked. I find this exercise very interesting. I'm just wondering if my solution is odd or not, and is there a much more normal way someone with experience might have solved this same issue? I'm just trying to improve my coding. I'm all self taught, so just looking for feedback. Thanks!

```
# F. front_back
# Consider dividing a string into two halves.
# If the length is even, the front and back halves are the same length.
# If the length is odd, we'll say that the extra char goes in the front half.
# e.g. 'abcde', the front half is 'abc', the back half 'de'.
# Given 2 strings, a and b, return a string of the form
#  a-front + b-front + a-back + b-back
def front_back(a, b):
  # +++your code here+++
  lengthABack = len(a)/2
  lengthAFront = len(a)/2 + len(a)%2
  lengthBBack = len(b)/2
  lengthBFront = len(b)/2 + len(b)%2
  return a[:lengthAFront]+b[:lengthBFront]+a[-lengthABack:]+b[-lengthBBack:]
```

Comment: It looks like a pretty standard way to solve the problem - the `len(a)%2` is clever, but this is otherwise a fairly straightforward translation of the problem statement. You could optimize slightly by calculating a single split point and just doing `a[:split]`, `a[split:]`, but it's not really a big deal.

Comment: this solution is fine. I would personally not needlessly call `len`, so `length_a = len(a)`. And if you are going to use Python, you should probably stick to `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for local variables.

Comment: @ nneonneo Awesome. Thanks for the really quick input!

Comment: Always indent 4 spaces, use spaces around operators and use `snake_cased` variables. Beyond that, this is a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com (although it might be a bit too insubstantial for that, so read their [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly shorter and maybe more Pythonic solution:

```
def front_back(a, b):
    a_split = (len(a) + 1) // 2
    b_split = (len(b) + 1) // 2
    return a[:a_split] + b[:b_split] + a[a_split:] + b[b_split:]
```

We use `(len(a) + 1) // 2` here because it mathematically gives the same result as `len(a)/2 + len(a)%2` but involves only one evaluation of `len(a)`.